# How to fade a page in and out using divs when clicking the nav link

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page set up with an ajax nav bar. I open the various pages in a Div id when you click the various links in the nav bar. I would like them to fade in and out.

here is the code for fading the splash page image out when clicking any link in the navbar

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("a").click(function() {
         $(".moon1").fadeOut(2000);
     });
 });
```

here is the div id i open the various navlinks in-

```
<div id="page"></div>
```

here is the code i used to open links in the div id when clicking a link in the navbar. This specific code is in a separate .js-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        link=$(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
        })
        .done(function(php) {
            $("#page").empty().append(php);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

all of this code works properly and to my satisfaction. i merely want to fade the various pages in and out when going from page to page. Thank you

Comment: If I understand you only add $(".moon1").fadeIn(2000); into your ajax .done function right?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

1) FadeOut before ajax send
2) FadeIn after ajax successful

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        link=$(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            beforeSend: $('.moon1').fadeOut(2000)
        })
        .done(function(php) {
            $('.moon1').fadeIn(1000);
            $("#page").empty().append(php);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```